# Foreign key referencing composite primary key

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two tables, where one of them contains a composite primary key, and the other contains a foreign key that references that composite primary key.

The problem with this solution is that doctrine 2 does not support it, and symfony metadata builder throws me the following error:

`It is not possible to map entity 'First' with a composite primary key as part of the primary key of another entity 'Second#keyname'`

I don't want to change the database structure, as it's already filled up database, production's copy, I don't want to make any changes to the structure and generate unnecessary posibilities for errors to occur.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Could you go through these use cases and select the one that is closest to what you are trying to do? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html.

Comment: Can you show your entity definitions? This is definitely doable. In your mapping you should not associate the foreign key to the entity with the composite key but to the original entity with the simple key (the key that actually uniquely identifies an entity).